# How to get TD value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the TD value using Value attribute....

Suppose i have fallowing html mark-up

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" value="FO2180TL" class="colPadding" id="salesOrderNumber1">bla bla <td>
```

then i tried this-

```
var  soNum = $('#salesOrderNumber1').val()
```

Which should return me `FO2180TL` but it didn't.
How Can i get that TD value...
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#salesOrderNumber1').attr("value");
```

Answer (score 4):

i think you should use
`$('#salesOrderNumber1').attr('value');`
instead
[jquery selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)
[Jquery ref selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: i think you should go check those llinks first 
[Jquery slection](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by `$('#salesOrderNumber1').attr('value');`